How do I fix these errors with pytesseract?
I am attempting to create a very simple program that can scan a specific part of the screen and print any text that is found. For some reason, I've been running into a set of errors that I can't find anything about online.
This is the code I've written.
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\chad\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\pytesseract.exe'

image = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(490, 337, 928, 458))
words = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang="eng")
print(words)

When run, the following errors occur at the second to last line.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chad\Visual_Studio_Code\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    words = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang="eng")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\chad\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 423, in 
image_to_string
    return {
           ^
  File "C:\Users\chad\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 426, in 
<lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\chad\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 288, in 
run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chad\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 264, in 
run_tesseract
    raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (2, 'Usage: pytesseract [-l lang] input_file')      

I have no idea what's going on, so any help at all would be appreciated greatly.

I was not able to reproduce your error with your code. The only difference is the path pointing to the tesseract command. What I do find concerning is that the tesseract executable should be named tesseract.exe not pytesseract.exe. Did you properly install tesseract with pytesseract?

For reference, the windows installation for tesseract found here would typically place the executable at AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe

I see what my issue was now. I was using the path for pytesseract, not tesseract itself. Thank you!
